# How to use symbols in a string?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, coding-style

This line will not compile in Visual C++

```
printf("x=%"PRIszu")\n",
```

Even though the symbol is defined:

```
#define PRIszu    "Iu"
```

I get the following error:

> Error C3688   invalid literal suffix 'PRIszu'; literal operator or
>   template 'operator ""PRIszu' not found

So how do I fix this print line to make use of the defined symbol?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/2dPVOp

Comment: @MatthewMoss I updated the question with the error

Comment: I get the error message that printf() does not support the 'I' flag (capital I)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps...?

```
printf("x=%" PRIszu "\n", yourVar);
```

I suspect you are using a C++11 compiler, which permits *user-defined literals*. See the answer here: [Using macro with string fails on VC 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738796/using-macro-with-string-fails-on-vc-2015)

Comment: The OP had a problem with parentheses, but these extra spaces should not be necessary: `printf("x=%"PRIszu"\n", yourVar);` should work fine too.

Comment: For C++11, it becomes necessary, to distinguish from user-defined literals. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738796/using-macro-with-string-fails-on-vc-2015