# Using macro with string fails on VC 2015

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2015, user-defined-literals

Why does this fail to compile?

```
char programDate[] = "("__DATE__")";
```

But this compiles fine (see space):

```
char programDate[] = "(" __DATE__")";
```

I do know VC2015 now supports literal-operators. But shouldn't that be in compilation phase? `__DATE__` should have been processed by the pre-processor. What is going on here?

I thought of some mix-match issue with Unicode/non-Unicode build - but it doesn't help. It's not just issue with pre-defined macros, but with user defined also:

```
#define MACRO "abc"
char data[] = "("MACRO")";
```

EDIT:

```
Error C3688 invalid literal suffix '__DATE__'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""__DATE__' not found
```

Comment: I think you may be on to something in your comment about user defined literals. Generally C++ parsers are **maximum munch**, for each token they gulp in as many characters as possible until it's no longer a valid token.

Comment: You could write the compilation error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since C++11, *user-defined literals* exist and are part of preprocessing.  The grammar is:

```
preprocessing-token:
    user-defined-string-literal
    // other stuff...

user-defined-string-literal:
    string_literal ud-suffix

ud-suffix:
    identifier
```

So `"("__DATE__` matches *preprocessing-token*, but `"("` `__DATE__` doesn't (that is two separate preprocessing tokens).

Macro replacement happens after tokenization. Since there is no token `__DATE__` in your first example, there is no replacement.

Comment: In case anyone didn't realize the C++ preprocessor differs from the C preprocessor... now you do :)

Comment: With C++11 user-defined literals in VS 2015, you can also run into problems with ``L"Hello, "L"World"`` would work before but fails with the same error because it tries to use the second L as a UDF. You fix it with whitespace: ``L"Hello, " L"World"``

Comment: And thankfully now mismatched strings can be concatenated - so second `L` isn't needed! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809141/concatenating-mismatched-string-works-in-vc2015-how)

Comment: Was it changed because it conflicts with postfix string operators `"Hello world"s` ? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s