# Concatenating mismatched string WORKS in VC2015 - How?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, c++14

When we have either of these:

```
auto city1 = "New "  L"Delhi";
auto city2 = L"New " "York";
```

Any pre-VS2015 compiler would raise error:

> error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings

But with VC2015 compiler, it compiles well and the resultant type (`auto` deduction) is a wide-char string.

My question is: When and How this is made possible - any standard specification?

Comment: This might help : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++03 this behaviour would be undefined.

ISO 14882-2003: 2.13.4.3 states that

> In translation phase 6 (2.1), adjacent narrow string literals are
>   concatenated and adjacent wide string literals are concatenated. If a
>   narrow string literal token is adjacent to a wide string literal
>   token, the behavior is undefined. Characters in concatenated strings
>   are kept distinct.

Not sure exactly when the change was introduced but the behaviour is at least well defined in the draft N3242 of the standard.

ISO 14882-2011: 2.14.5.13 states that

> In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated. If both string literals have the same encoding-prefix, the resulting concatenated string literal has that encoding-prefix. If one string literal has no encoding-prefix, it is treated as a string literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand.

Therefore, in your case, `auto` is correctly deduced as a wide string literal.