# upgrading solution from visual studio 2013 to visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, icu

I am trying to upgrade a solution file containing 35 project, I used "Devenv" command to upgrade the solution file, I checked in project file it is getting updated but when I tried to build solution it started to throw error(solution was running perfectly fine on VS2013). Error message are

**error message: MSB3073 The command "NMAKE /f makedata.mak ICUMAKE=" C:\research\release\source\icu\icuc\source\data\" CFG= release clean all" exited with error code 2**

**NMAKE : fatal error v1073 : don't know how to make "C:\research\release\source\icu\icuc\bin\pkgdata.exe"**

**some more error message:**

Error   C2248   'icu_4_0::Format::Format': cannot access protected member declared in class 'icu_4_0::Format'   i18n    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\i18n\unicode\measfmt.h  72

Error   C2248   'icu_4_0::Format::Format': cannot access protected member declared in class 'icu_4_0::Format'   i18n    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\i18n\unicode\measfmt.h  72

Error   C2248   'icu_4_0::Format::Format': cannot access protected member declared in class 'icu_4_0::Format'   i18n    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\i18n\unicode\measfmt.h  72

Error   C2109   subscript requires array or pointer type    io  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\io\ufile.c  67

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'INVC_DATA_NAME'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""INVC_DATA_NAME' not found    genuca  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\tools\genuca\genuca.cpp 398

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'UCA_DATA_NAME'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""UCA_DATA_NAME' not found  genuca  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\tools\genuca\genuca.cpp 760

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  412

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1251

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1289

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1290

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1297

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1355

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1358

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  intltest    c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\intltest\intltest.cpp  1361

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  104

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  107

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  110

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  131

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  745

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  748

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  iotest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\iotest\iotest.cpp  751

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  letest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\letest\letest.cpp  418

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  letest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\letest\letest.cpp  419

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  letest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\letest\letest.cpp  426

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  letest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\letest\letest.cpp  1026

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  letest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\letest\letest.cpp  1029

Error   C3688   invalid literal suffix 'U_FILE_SEP_STRING'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""U_FILE_SEP_STRING' not found  letest  c:\users\rajeevku\perforce\rajeevku_rajeevku-w7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\test\letest\letest.cpp  1032

Error   MSB3073 The command "NMAKE /f makedata.mak ICUMAKE="C:\Users\rajeevku\Perforce\rajeevku_RAJEEVKU-W7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\data\" CFG=debug" exited with code 2.  makedata    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   38

Error   U1077   '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link.exe"' : return code '0xc0000135'  makedata    C:\Users\rajeevku\Perforce\rajeevku_RAJEEVKU-W7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\data\NMAKE  1

Error   U1077   'C:\Users\rajeevku\Perforce\rajeevku_RAJEEVKU-W7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\bin\pkgdata.EXE' : return code '0x2'  makedata    C:\Users\rajeevku\Perforce\rajeevku_RAJEEVKU-W7-1_lipika\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\data\NMAKE  1

Comment: For VS13 to VS15 you don't need to upgrade, upgrade is required for solution made on vs10 below ...

Comment: I know that, still I want to port my solution to VS2015.

Comment: open the solution without devenv, and in project menu is there any option to  Upgrade,If there is then only the project will be Upgraded else it is waste of time

Comment: yes it opens a popup window for upgrade on opening in VS2015. when I opened it without running Devenv command, popup window appeared saying upgrade project I did upgrade by clicking ok, even in that case, Build is failing.

Comment: By any chance your system date time is wrong?please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075279/how-do-i-fix-msb3073-error-in-my-post-build-event

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/112336

Comment: system date time is ok, I tried  porting and build process on two different machine.

Comment: was the above link helpful?

Comment: not of much use.. I Already had visited those link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738796/using-macro-with-string-fails-on-vc-2015   I resolved all error except the 1st two .. anyone plz help me in resolving 1st 2bug

Comment: ni idea!Bro,all i can say is there is something wrong with Path..C:\research\release\source\icu\icuc\bin\pkgdata.exe

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal   in VS2015 user-defined literals support has been added it is what that was causing problem. anyway thanks :)   resolved all :)